# Valores variables en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un header que muestra un título dependiendo de la página donde te encuentres. El caso es que cuando en código se llama al encabezado, la variable aún no ha cogido el valor:

```
$subHeading = '--';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    require_once('view/header.php');

    if(isset($_GET['orderList'])){
        require_once('view/view_getOrders.php');
        $men_order = true;
        $subHeading = 'Orders';
    }
}
```

En este caso el titulo muestra el valor al inicializar -- en lugar de Orders... ¿Qué forma sería la correcta de abordar esto? (Espero haberme explicado bien)

Comment: Inicialmente, sin ver nada más en el código, las comprobaciones no podrían ir todas antes de las cosas de presentación como la inclusión del header.php?

Comment: Y que pasa si pones Orders arriba y -- abajo? debería de hacer lo contrario a lo que te esta sucediendo. en mi opinión en tu header nunca llega a cambiar ya que le estas asignado después del header, no se también es confuso lo que quieres hacer o como lo has explicado.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que haces despues con la variable $subHeading? si la usas dentro de header.php, lo más probable es que siempre coja el valor "--" ya que está definido antes del require, pero... haría falta más código para saber que pueda pasar.

Comment: @Alfabravo no por el orden de las vistas

Comment: @Artudoxo exactamente, cuando saco el header no está cambiado el valor de la variable por lo tanto coge el valor -- en lugar de Orders

Comment: @DiegoMartin hago solo un echo de $subHeading dentro de header.php

Comment: ahí está el problema, cuando haces el echo imprime lo que tiene la variable en ese instante. Si quieres que el titulo cambie deberías comprobarlo y/o cambiarlo antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una idea que se me ocurre es que cambies el orden:

```
$subHeading = '--';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){

    if(isset($_GET['orderList'])){
        $view = 'view/view_getOrders.php';
        $men_order = true;
        $subHeading = 'Orders';
    }



    require_once('view/header.php');
    require_once($view);
}
```

A ver así

Comment: Efectivamente, al alterar el orden funciona correctamente, he reestructurado un poco el código y he usado tu recomendación y funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ;) Nada, para eso estamos.